# Compile object file for PAM module with curl

Tags: c, gcc, curl, pam

I'm writing a PAM module and I need to do a https request each time that a user logs in. I implemented already that using curl but the problem is that as soon as I introduce the curl include in my C code, the module stops working.

Here are the commands I use to compile it:

> gcc -fPIC -fno-stack-protector -c mypam.c
>
> sudo ld -x --shared -o /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/security/mypam.so mypam.o

It compiles without problems but the pam module is not being interpreted. 
If I delete the curl part it works fine (I added the necesary lines to use `mypam.so`)

I think that the problem is with gcc that I am not indicating that I want to use CURL. I tried `gcc -fPIC -fno-stack-protector -c mypam.c -lcurl` but it complains:

`mypam.c: In function ‘pam_sm_authenticate’:
mypam.c:593:2: error: unknown type name ‘pr’`

Any idea what is happening?? If I compile it as a normal program with a `main` function and use the command: `gcc -ggdb -Wall -Wextra -o fo fo.c -lcrypto -lm -lcurl` it works fine.

CODE:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <security/pam_appl.h>
#include <security/pam_modules.h>
#include <security/pam_ext.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>


#include <curl/curl.h>

void foo(void){
    CURL *curl;
    CURLcode res;

    curl = curl_easy_init();

    // If I just put here a printf("Hello!");  it works
}


/* expected hook */
PAM_EXTERN int pam_sm_setcred( pam_handle_t *pamh, int flags, int argc, const char **argv ) {
    return PAM_SUCCESS;
}

PAM_EXTERN int pam_sm_acct_mgmt(pam_handle_t *pamh, int flags, int argc, const char **argv){
    return PAM_SUCCESS;
}

/* expected hook, this is where custom stuff happens */
PAM_EXTERN int pam_sm_authenticate( pam_handle_t *pamh, int flags,int argc, const char **argv ) {
    int retval;
    const char* pUsername;

    retval = pam_get_user(pamh, &pUsername, "Username: ");

    printf("Welcome %s\n", pUsername);
    foo();

    if (retval != PAM_SUCCESS) {
        return retval;
    }

    return PAM_AUTHINFO_UNAVAIL;
}
```

As you can see the code is super easy. If i just include curl it works but if I reference anything in the curl library (as `CURL *curl;` it breaks).
Any idea?
Thank you!

Comment: @Wug I updated the post with the code. I hope it can be useful

Comment: Sorry but I don't have enough knowledge of PAM to help any further, hopefully the code will help someone else who knows more than I do.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you aren't linking with libpam for one thing, so that is going to be a problem.  In general I like to test a pam module by dlopening it and then looking for the symbols that the module expects with dlsym.  This is essentially what the pam library does when it you configure the pam.conf.  It finds the library and dlopens it and looks for given symbols.  So here is a bit of test code you can run on your compiled pam module.

```
#include <dlfcn.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, const char* argv[])
{
    if ( argc != 2 )
    {
            printf("Usage: ./dlopentest <path_to_pam_module>\n");
            exit(1);
    }
    void *libhandle = dlopen(argv[1], RTLD_NOW);
    if ( libhandle == NULL )
    {
            printf("%s",dlerror());
            exit(1);
    }
    void* sym = dlsym(libhandle,"pam_sm_authenticate");
    if ( sym == NULL )
    {
            printf("%s",dlerror());
            exit(1);
    }
    sym = dlsym(libhandle,"pam_sm_setcred");
    if ( sym == NULL )
    {
            printf("%s",dlerror());
            exit(1);
    }
    dlclose(libhandle);
}
```

Obviously not all of the pam_sm_* symbols are being tested, just test the ones you expect your module to have.

Build and link this with -ldl, and then run it on your pam module shared object.  It should complain verbosely about whatever is causing your module to fail to load once you configure it in pam.conf.  This is significantly easierto debug though, and it can be incorporated easily into a unit test.  I would recommend this sort "dlopentest" to anyone who is developing a serious pam module.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue too.
As a workaround I separated my cURL related functions from the pam module.
Now the pam module executes the program with cURL and handles the result code,
like:

```
char *my_args[5];
pid_t pid;

my_args[0] = "myprogram_with_curl";
my_args[1] = pUsername;
my_args[2] = pPassword;
my_args[3] = NULL;

pid = fork();
int status;
if (pid) //retrieve result from myprogram_with_curl
{
  pid = waitpid(pid, &status, 0);
  if (status != 0)
  {
    return PAM_AUTH_ERR;
  } 
}
else
{
  execv("/usr/bin/myprogram_with_curl", my_args);
  printf("sad! execv failed\n"); 
}
```